# Passing counter variable from controller to View in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, controller, view, laravel-blade

I am trying to make a counter in my laravel site. This counter takes all the comments from model *Comments* which were created from Carbon::now() until startofMonth(). So I have my controller and function counter as so:

```
 class CommentsController extends Controller
{
        public function counter()
    {
        $new_comments=Comments::where('created_at', Carbon::now()->startofMonth())->get();

        $counted->count($new_comments['created_at']);


        return View::make('pages.dashboard')->with('new_comments', $counted);        
    }
}
```

My blade template:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-3">
             <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
       </div>
           <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
              <div class="huge">{{!!$new_comments!!}}</div>
              <div>New Comments!</div>
</div>
```

I keep getting a variable undefined error message even though the variable is called in the controller! The dashboard page works fine when the variable is not called in the blade template.

EDIT:

I have managed to get this working if ignore the controller and add the following into my view:

```
{{App\Comments::count()}}
```

This only shows the total amount of rows in the table Comments, but I will try and add the mySQL query in to it.

I still don't know why it can't be called as a variable from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your blade template, you are calling it correctly but ! brings such issues `{{!!$new_comments!!}}` it will say variable undefined.

Try it without !!, It worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this, still says variable undefined.... could it be a problem with the route? Do I even need one for calling this variable from the controller?

Comment: I don't think so route can be an issue here, as you already said "The dashboard page works fine when the variable is not called in the blade template."

Comment: Is rest of variable calling working fine for other templates in your project?

Comment: Yes I can call variables for tables in my index function of the same controller.

Comment: Strange, then why not for this one. I suggest you to compare it with some other file, which is working fine.

Comment: Yes I have tried this. It seems as though the controller is not pushing the view::make to the page

Answer (score 0):

First: you want to take all comments are created from begin of month to now, you need a whereBetween query, not equal.

Second: You call a undefined variable $counted. I think you need remove

```
$counted->count($new_comments['created_at']);
```

and pass $new_comments to view instead of $counted

```
return View::make('pages.dashboard')->with('new_comments', $new_comments);
```

and display comments count in view

```
{{ $new_comments->count() }}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Thank you for your comment, although this still gives a variable undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a late answer, but I believe you're passing your variables incorrectly with the `->with()` function. From my experience with Laravel, `->with()` uses an array syntax for passing multiple variables to a view. For example:

```
 return View::make('pages.dashboard')
 ->with(["new_comments" => $new_comments, "counted" => $counted]);
 // Note the array usage, works with [] or array()
```

Then, in your `dashboard.blade.php` you can call either `{{ $new_comments }}` or `{!! $new_comments !!}` to echo out that value (one ignores HTML markup, one includes it.)

On a side note, trying to echo out the contents of an Eloquent collection (i.e. `Comment::get()` as opposed to something like `Comment::first()`) may not work. You should loop over the results and echo accordingly:

```
@foreach($new_comments AS $new_comment)
{!! $new_comment->created_at !!}
...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't work, still the variable is undefined. I'm not sure if there is a conflict somewhere with how the page is 'made' with ::make. It seems as though the page is not reading the in the variable from the controller. All other variables in the same controller are being read in. Rather bizarre.

Comment: If you run `dd($new_comments);` in your controller right before `View::make()` what does it return?

Comment: It doesn't return anything, same undefined variable message

Comment: So the issue lies in your controller, and not in passing the value to the view. `dd()` is short-hand for `die(var_dump($variable));`, so if running that in your controller produces an error, there is something wrong with the definition on `$new_comments = Comments::where('created_at', Carbon::now()->startofMonth())->get();`

Comment: I have tried: 
    `$new_comments=Comments::all():
        dd($new_comments);
        return View::make('pages.dashboard')->with('new_comments', $comments);`
Still "Variable undefined"

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? I'm sure it says more than just "Variable Undefined"

Comment: The error message is vast however this is what I receive:

ErrorException in ce2e2c6c48aef87dfc501da15b5f908b line 19: Undefined variable: new_comments (View: /home/martin/Projects/inventory_app/resources/views/pages/dashboard.blade.php)

Comment: Also this if it is any help:

at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/martin/Projects/inventory_app/storage/framework/views/ce2e2c6c48aef87dfc501da15b5f908b', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 58
at CompilerEngine->get('/home/martin/Projects/inventory_app/resources/views/pages/dashboard.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 135

Answer (score 0):

This was solved. I was calling the return view::make(dashboard) in another (page)controller. This controller took precedent therefore this view did not occur. Therefore in my pagecontroller I applied the following:

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        $count = Comments::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::today())->count();

        return View::make('pages.dashboard')->with('new_comments_count', $count);
    }
```

I can then call new_comments_count in my view.
Many thanks for the help.